# I need help identifying errors in my JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, html

So, it's the first time ever I code in JS & HTML, I'm trying to make a Game of 'Rock Paper Scissors, Here's the code:

```
<body>
    <button>Rock</button>
    <button>Paper</button>
    <button>Scissors</button>
    <button class = "well">well</button>
    <div class="result"></div>

    <script>
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

        for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                const player = buttons[i].innerHTML;
                const robot = buttons [Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length)].innerHTML;
                let resultat = "";

                if (player === robot) {
                    resultat = "It's a Tie ^^";
                }

                else if ((player === "Rock" && robot === "Scissors") 
                      || (player === "Paper" && robot === "Rock")
                      || (player === "Scissors" && robot === "Paper")) {
                    result = "You won :)";
                }

                else if ((player === "well")) {
                    result = "CHEATER !!!";
                }

                else {
                    result = "You Lost :/";
                }

                document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = 
                `player : ${player} </br>
                 robot : ${robot} </br>
                 ${result}`;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I keep getting a bunch of errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "you get a bunch of errors" it's best you actually include those errors in the question. I'd also consider using an editor that help avoid simple syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the closing parathesis for buttons[i].addEventListener. at the bottom, last-second one just after the curly brace, you need to add `)`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button>Rock</button>
    <button>Paper</button>
    <button>Scissors</button>
    <button class = "well">well</button>
    <div class="result"></div>

    <script>
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

        for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                const player = buttons[i].innerHTML;
                const robot = buttons [Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length)].innerHTML;
                let resultat = "";

                if (player === robot) {
                    resultat = "Egalité ^^";
                }

                else if ((player === "Rock" && robot === "Scissors") 
                      || (player === "Paper" && robot === "Rock")
                      || (player === "Scissors" && robot === "Paper")) {
                    result = "You won :)";
                }

                else if ((player === "puit")) {
                    result = "CHEATER !!!";
                }

                else {
                    result = "You Lost :/";
                }

                document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = `player : ${player} </br> robot : ${robot} </br> ${result}`;
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: If it's caused by a typo, then comment that fact rather than answering, and flag the question as such.

Comment: @JackBashford Okay, Will take care of this from next time.